# Cannot instantiate bean org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hibernate

Unable to initialize the Spring container. I am seeing the following error
Note:  I have both javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar, persistence-api-1.0.2.jar in my classpath. I have struggled to understand, which one should i use in my project. Mine is a simple Spring app deployed to Tomcat. Please see comments below.

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)

My goal is to instantiate this bean and move forward in my migration. I googled a lot and couldn't find a satisfying answer. I looked at the source code of Spring's LocalSessionFactoryBean also.

Should i set hibernateProperties as a Map instead of Properties?

I am using Spring 5.1.8, Hibernate 5.3.10.FINAL, Java 8 with Postgres database. I am actually migrating from Spring 1.2, hibernate 3.

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryassets" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSourceassets" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources" value="/com/startup/core/persistence/assets/ObjectMappings.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: please have a look here: https://github.com/Apress/pro-spring-5/blob/master/chapter07/hibernate-base/src/main/java/com/apress/prospring5/ch7/config/AppConfig.java

Comment: but the problem is, you are using xml. Who uses that? nobody.

Comment: @Faraz Durrani the xml config matches programmatic declaration. Both are setting Properties, but the underlying Hibernate class is expecting a Map. If you see the stack trace, you will notice it.

Comment: @Faraz  Not sure, if this is the root cause of my problem.
I have javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar,  persistence-api-1.0.2.jar  in my classpath.
I have struggled to understand, which one should i use in my project. Mine is a Spring application deployed to a Tomcat. It's not a J2EE application.
And I am using Spring managed transactions. I am not using entityManager, but staright HQL ans SQL using sessionFactory.

Comment: sridharkondoji 1 second let me check something

Comment: try this: https://github.com/Serge009/Professional-Java-for-Web-Applications/blob/master/Chapter%2021/Eclipse/Spring-JPA/source/production/java/com/wrox/config/RootContextConfiguration.java

Comment: and have one persistence api. try this one: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: oh you said you are not using entityManager? I don't know how can you implement persistence without entity manager? Sorry this is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Faraz Durrani Appreciate your help. Spring gives me access to SessionFactory directly and manages transactions. That's what I meant. However, I will try to remove one of the older persistent-api jar and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple versions of persistence api jars in the classpath confused Spring. As soon as i removed persistence-api-1.0.2 and kept javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar, my error went away. However, I didn't try using  eclipse's persistence jar as suggested by Faraz Durrani.
However, Faraz Durrani did point me in the right direction.
Thank you.